# Rails Delayed_Job debug undefined method being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I've a delayed job that is being called somewhere, and I've no idea where in my code base is calling it.

The delayed job is error-ing out due to:

```
undefined method `payment_completed' for NotificationsMailer:Class
```

the problem is, i can't find the method payment_completed anywhere in my codebase at all.

Somewhere & Somebody is calling that delayed job. is there a way to find out who is firing this delayed job?

Comment: is it in your `mailers` directory?

Comment: yeah  NotificationsMailer:Class is in the mailers directory